# Ajax success function not working before $("#form_id").submit()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am using ajax for deletion and then trigger form submit using Jquery as in the code.

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url()?>/welcome/delete", {
acc:dlt},function(response){
          alert(response);
});

$( "#myForm" ).submit();
```

The problem is that the `alert(response)` doesn't popup in spite of the success of ajax. BUT if I remove the `$( "#myForm" ).submit();` line then the alert pops up and works fine.

Please tell me how to make this response function work fine followed by        `.submit()` function.

Thank you so much. If my way of questioning was in any way a bit confusing pardon me , I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I want the submission to be independent of the ajax function.

Comment: `$( "#myForm" ).submit()` causes the browser to navigate to a new page?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't confusing, but what you are trying to do is a little.

When you submit the form, you are basically leaving the page, so the browser ignores the ajax response.

You could wait until the ajax call returns before you submit the form:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url()?>/welcome/delete", { acc: dlt }, function(response) {
    alert(response);
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: I want the form submission to be independent of the ajax function.

Comment: @user3602022 - But if you are submitting the form, you are leaving the page, so you can't expect to be able to process the ajax response. Or are you also submitting the form via ajax?

Comment: No I am not using ajax for form submission.

Comment: @user3602022 you can't separate the 2 if you want them both to happen. AJAX is asynchronous and must have time to complete

Answer (score 1):

When you have this code:

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url()?>/welcome/delete", {
acc:dlt},function(response){
          alert(response);
});

$( "#myForm" ).submit();
```

What you are doing is specifying a callback function that executes *sometime later*, when you receive the response for your AJAX request. While waiting for the response, the code continues to execute. So the order of events is:

1. The `$.post(...)` request is sent.
2. `$( "#myForm" ).submit();`. At this point, you submit the form and leave the page.
3. A response comes back from the request in step 1, but since you've left the page, the code inside the callback function `alert(response);` is not executed.

For a possible solution to the problem, see John's answer. But if that doesn't resolve your problem, you will need to clarify why you want the form submit to be independent of the AJAX callback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answers by @John S and @user3250365 , I actually understand now that Ajax followed by form submission sometimes causes problem like in my case , form submitted first without waiting for the Ajax response. So as a solution I just got rid of the Ajax call and instead the array which I was sending via Ajax , Now I stored  it inside one of the hidden fields in my form and sent it through form submit.

Here's my field (Hidden):

```
<input id = "dlts" name = "dlts" type = "hidden"></input>
```

Here's how I store my array(named dlt) inside the field:

```
var arrayString = JSON.stringify( dlt );
$('#dlts').val( arrayString );
```

And this is how I access it in my controller(Using php MVC , codeigniter)

```
$dlts = json_decode($this->input->post('dlts'), true);
```